# Databricks: writeStream not processing data

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks

I am working on a Databricks training, having a hard time to get a writeStream query to work. Maybe I am not catching the whole concept of streaming correctly. I have a path with 20 JSON files, which I am able to read, by doing:

```
ordersJsonPath = "dbfs:/user/dbacademy/developer-foundations-capstone/raw/orders/stream/*"
ordersDF = (spark.readStream
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
.schema(userDefinedSchema)
.json(ordersJsonPath)
```

When running "display(ordersDF)", I can see that the 20 JSON get added sequentially to the dataframe with the correct schema. However, when I want to write the files in a table with the same schema, nothing gets processed. My code for the streamWrite is:

```
checkpointPath = "dbfs:/user/dbacademy/developer-foundations-capstone/checkpoint/orders"
orders = (ordersDF.writeStream
.format("delta")
.queryName("ordersQuery")
.outputMode("append")
.trigger(processingTime="1 second")
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.table("orders"))
```

The writeStream query runs but does not show any result (and the table does not get updated). Since I am not getting any error message, it is hard so say whats wrong, but it appears there is just no real connection between the read and the write query. Do I need to run both queries at the same time or sequentially? Or am I confusing things here and I need 2 different dataframes for read and write?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the checkPointPath and run it again.